# Deploying a Spring Boot web application as a service to Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that I want to start using `System V Init`. My jar file is in `/var/my-app/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. So, I created a symbolic link using the command below

`sudo ln -s /var/my-app/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /etc/init.d/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

without any issue. However, when I try

`sudo service my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT start`

I get the error:

```
/etc/init.d/my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: 1: /etc/init.d/myapp-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does a symbolic link have to do with the service? Nothing :)

You will first have to define the Upstart script (in case of Ubuntu 14.04 ), it is in /etc/init/ and ending in .conf. (http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/)

```
# <service name>.conf
start on filesystem
exec /usr/bin/java -jar /path_to/program
```

in case of Ubuntu 16.06+ (you can find nice article [here](https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-on-ubuntu))

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/my-webapp.service
```

Then you can run it as:

```
sudo service <your service name> start
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try this in a few days (deployment is held off for a few days) and will accept this as the answer if it works. Thanks.